# Required message not showing for p:fileUpload after using Primefaces 5.0

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, message

Earlier I used primefaces 3.5 to show required message for p:fileUpload and that time it was showing on my website. As I upgraded to primefaces 5.0 required message for p:fileUpload is not shown. Below is the code :

```
<h:form id="uploadPForm" class="form-horizontal row-border" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<span>
<p:messages autoUpdate="false" closable="true" id="msgsuccess" severity="info"/>
<p:messages autoUpdate="false" closable="true" id="msgerror" severity="fatal,error"/>
</span>
<p:fileUpload id="appUpload" mode="simple"
required="true requiredMessage="#msg['appUpload.Required']}" 
value="#{appUploadBean.file}"  style="width:228px;">        
</p:fileUpload>
</h:form>
```

Comment: On your `<p:fileUpload>` tag your missing the `"` at the end of `required="true`, is it this way in your code?

Comment: Sorry, i did mistake while writing my query here. On my side, it is in proper way i.e. required="true"